# Digit-only input keycode verifier also accepting forward-slash

Tags: javascript, input

I wrote a piece of code which will only accept numeric value as key event. It should only accept 0-9 and backspace. But it also allows forward slash as input.

```
  element.addEventListener('keypress',function(event){
            var charcodeAcceptable=[47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,8];
            if (window.event) {
               var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
            }
            else if (event) {
               var charCode = event.which;
            }


          if(charcodeAcceptable.indexOf(charCode)==-1){
             event.preventDefault();

          }
      });
```

Comment: is your forward slash located on the same key as a 0-9 digit?

Comment: as far as i know forward slash keycode is 191

Comment: You have included `47` in your `charcodeAcceptable` and `47` is `/`

Comment: it says 191 :/  https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Check here :) http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/slash-forward-slash-fraction-bar-division-ascii-code-47.html

Comment: @AL-zami the key-code at keydown and the represents the key, while the in the keypress it represents the resulting char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASCII code for the forward slash `/` is 47, therefore your `indexOf` returns 0 and not -1.

Answer (score 0):

After my orginal response quoted below, and based on the comment left by @t.niese I have created an updated pen.

http://codepen.io/ballerton/pen/PzOdxW

Essentialy, use `event.key` to get the value of the key press and then test against allowed values:

```
  element.addEventListener('keypress',function(event){
    var charcodeAcceptable=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','Backspace'];
    if (window.event) {
       var charCode = window.event.key;
    }
    else if (event) {
       var charCode = event.key;
    }


  if(charcodeAcceptable.indexOf(charCode)==-1){
     event.preventDefault();

  }
 });
```

> I have modified the code to use event.keyCode and it works as
>   expected.
>
> http://codepen.io/ballerton/pen/vKWzRO
>
> ```
>   element.addEventListener('keypress',function(event){
>         var charcodeAcceptable=[47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,8];
>         if (window.event) {
>            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
>         }
>         else if (event) {
>            var charCode = event.keyCode;
>         }
>
>
>       if(charcodeAcceptable.indexOf(charCode)==-1){
>          event.preventDefault();
>
>       }
>   });
> ```
>
> original pen by Chris Coyier
>
> see comment by @t.niese
>
> With regard to the test itself, is it important t test to see if it is
>   a window event?
>
> If not could you not just use:
>
> ```
>   element.addEventListener('keypress',function(event){
>     var charcodeAcceptable=[47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,8];
>
>     if(charcodeAcceptable.indexOf(event.keyCode)==-1){
>        event.preventDefault();
>     }
>   });
> ```

Comment: Using `event.keyCode` instead of `event.which` will not solve the problem, in FF `event.keyCode` will be `0`. And you shouldn't  even use `keyCode` (and `which`) because it is deprecated: [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). `47` represents `/` in keypress so it has to be removed tom the `charcodeAcceptable`.